# Eclipse turn off autocomplete in HTML mode

Tags: html, eclipse, autocomplete

I really, really, really HATE eclipse web tools autocomplete.

I can't stand it.  It completes tags for me even if the tag has a typo

```
    <stronng></stronng>
```

I tried everything, completely disabling "content assist" in every single language mode I could find, and it STILL throws in the stupid end-tag, which I DON'T want.

Comment: I hate them too. ;) +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On 3.5 it's in prefs under Web->HTML Files->Editor->Typing.

Comment: That's been bugging me for 3 years. :)

Comment: What's `prefs`? Jk rofl

Answer (score 0):

If you have Zen Coding and Aptana you'll also need to turn off one or more of:

```
Eclipse > Prefs > Zen Coding > Expand abbrevs with tab key
Eclipse > Prefs > Apatana Studio > Editors > Auto insert closing tags
```